# Particular Regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a text string that looks as follows:

```
word word word {{t:word word|word}} word word {{t:word|word}} word word...
```

I'm interested to extract all strings that start with "{{t" and end with "}}". I don't care about the rest. I don't know in advance the number of words in "{{..|..}}". If it wasn't a space separating the words inside then splitting the text on space would work. I'm not sure how to write a regular expression to get this done. I thought about running over the text, char by char, and then store everything between "{{t:" and "}}", but would like to know a cleaner way to do the same.

Thank you!

**EDIT** 
Expected output from above:

An array of strings `String[] a` where `a[0]` is `{{t:word word|word}}` and `a[1]` is `{{t:word|word}}`.

Comment: So what exactly do you want as output from your example?

Comment: For example, String[] a, where a[0] is {{t:word word|word}} and a[1] is {{t:word|word}}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about (using non-greedy matching, so that it doesn't find ":word word|word}} word word {{t:word|word"

```
String s = "word word word {{t:word word|word}} word word {{t:word|word}} word word";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{t:(.*?)\\}\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    //System.out.println(m.group(1));
            System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Edit:

changed to m.group() so that results contain delimiters.

Answer (score 3):

using the `java.util.regex.*` package works miracles here

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{t(.*?)\\}\\}");//escaping + capturing group
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();//can also be a list or whatever
while(m.find()){
    result.add(m.group(1));
}
```

the capturing group can also be the entire regex to include the `{{` and `}}` like so `"(\\{\\{t.*?\\}\\})"`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class WordTest {
    public static void main( String ... args ) {
        String input = "word word word {{t:word word|word}} word word {{t:word|word}} word word...";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\{\\{.*?\\}\\})");
        Matcher m = p.matcher( input );
        while( m.find() ) {
            System.out.println( m.group(1) );
        }
    }
}
```